# C++ cycling callbacks are not executed when compiled with -O3

Tags: c++, multithreading, optimization

I'm trying to create a class that can cycle a set of callbacks indefinitely (part of a larger project but I isolated the problem back to this MWE). As you can see in the code below the idea is to cycle the callback on a seperate thread and print `PASS` every second. After 10 seconds the main should finish and the cycle object should be cleaned up and the thread stopped.

```
#include <chrono>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <thread>

class Cycle
{
public:
  using Callbacks = std::map<size_t, std::function<void()>>;

  Cycle(const Callbacks& callbacks = {}, const std::chrono::seconds& frequency = std::chrono::seconds(1)) : frequency_(frequency), counter(0), max(callbacks.empty() ? 0 : callbacks.rbegin()->first), callbacks_(callbacks) {}

  ~Cycle() { this->stop(); }

  void start()
  {
    this->t_ = std::thread([&]
      {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(this->m_cv_);
        while (!this->cv_.wait_for(lk, this->frequency_, [&]
          { return this->terminate_; }))
        {
          for (const auto& [interval, callback] : this->callbacks_)
          {
            if (this->counter % interval == 0)
              callback();
          }
          this->counter = (this->counter + 1) % (this->max);
        }
        lk.unlock();
        this->cv_.notify_one();
      });
  }

  void stop()
  {
    {
      std::lock_guard lk(this->m_cv_);
      this->terminate_ = true;
    }
    this->cv_.notify_one();
    this->t_.join();
  }

  void add(const std::chrono::seconds& interval, const std::function<void()>& callback)
  {
    size_t factor = interval / this->frequency_;
    this->callbacks_[factor] = callback;
    this->max = std::max(this->max, factor);
  }

private:
  mutable std::mutex m_cv_;
  std::condition_variable cv_;
  bool terminate_;
  const std::chrono::seconds frequency_;
  size_t counter;
  size_t max;
  std::thread t_;

  Callbacks callbacks_;
};

int main()
{
  Cycle cycle;
  cycle.add(std::chrono::seconds(1), [&]()
    { std::cout << "PASS" << std::endl; });
  cycle.start();

  std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(10));
}
```

when I compile this example with `g++ main.cpp -std=c++20 -lpthread` and run it, I see the expected output of

```
PASS
PASS
PASS
PASS
PASS
PASS
PASS
PASS
PASS
```

But when I compile this same example with `g++ main.cpp -std=c++20 -lpthread -O3` and run it, I get no output at all, as if the callback is never run.

Other answers have mentioned that maybe I have a bug and am relying on it unknowingly during normal compilation but it gets exposed when optimization occurs during compilation. But I do not really see where that could be.

Anyone any ideas why this gives different results for `-O3` (I also tested it with `clang++` but that gave the same results)

Comment: Looks like `terminate_` is not initialized.

Comment: Try to format the code in your question so it fits width-wise on a single screen. Good formatting makes your question easier to read and understand which helps increase participation and increases your odds of getting an answer.

Comment: *But I do not really see where that could be.* -- A good code sanitizer or similar program should detect that you forgot to initialize `terminate_`.

Comment: Why does your lambda try to notify itself? It is obviously useless.

Comment: And idea that you will uniquely identify a callback by its interval is quite strange... Though I do not know what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux That was it, thank you very much. Yes my formatter has no line breaks for formatting hence the long line for the constructor. I'll throw it through a different formatter next time with a fixed column width when posting a question.